# How to use actual google service to unit test google.maps.event.addListener

Tags: angular, unit-testing, google-maps, karma-jasmine

I found this tutorial of how to use autocomplete component from google maps: https://medium.com/@dhormale/use-google-places-api-autocomplete-using-angular-for-resident-and-office-address-23cc33078e8
But there is no example of how to unit test it.

Initially i had this peace of code:

```
      const googleMaps = jasmine.createSpyObj('Geocoder', ['geocode']);
      const googleAutocomplete = jasmine.createSpyObj('Autocomplete', ['getPlace']);

      function Geocoder(): any {
         return googleMaps;
      }

      function Autocomplete(): any {
         return googleAutocomplete;
      }

      window.google = {
         maps: {
            Geocoder,
            event: {
               addListener(): void {},
               trigger(): void {}
            },
            places: {
               Autocomplete
            }
         }
      } as any;
```

in my spec file, but in this case it skips the original callback of addListener

```
         const place = autocomplete.getPlace();

         const { name } = place;

         if (name) {
            this.invokeEvent(name);
         }
```

Without mocking window.google it throws errors like:
 `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Autocomplete')`